# Variable scope in jQuery AJAX requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Okay, I'm totally confused.  I'm sure this is a scoping or a closure thing, but could someone explain why

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var test = 0;
    var whatev = [1,2,3,4,5];
    $.each(whatev, function(i, v) {
        test += 1;
    });
    alert(test);
});
```

alerts "5" and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var test = 0;
    var whatev = [1,2,3,4,5];
    $.each(whatev, function(i, v) {
        $.ajax('http://example.com/').done(function(data) {
             test += 1;
        });             
    });
    alert(test);
});
```

alerts 0?  Why does the anonymous function in the `$.each` call have access to test but the anonymous function for the ajax call doesn't?  Where is that anonymous function being defined?

Comment: each is SYCHRONOUS, That Ajax call is ASYNCHRONOUS

Comment: `$.ajax('http://example.com/')` is asynchronous.

Comment: @epascarello: AHHHH, right.... someone didn't haven't enough coffee.

Comment: Careful with the AJAX calls in the `each` loop. You are on your way to DOS'ing your own server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback of JQuery `each` is synchronous.

The callback of JQuery Ajax **(asynchronous javascript and xml)**  however is asynchronous.

If you want the ajax function to be synchronous you can do it as such:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://example.com/",
    async: false
})
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the async option... works like a charm now!

Answer (score 2):

That is because

```
$.ajax('http://example.com/').done();
```

is asynchronous.

```
function(data) {
    test += 1;
}
```

is being called after all the code has been executed.

Comment: @Andrew Np, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

you could work with callbacks, everything will wait for

the loop waits for ajax callback and the alert waits for finishing the loop

```
function request(callback){
        $.ajax('http://example.com/').done(function(data) {

             callback();
        });  
}

var y = 0;
function loop(whatev,callback){
   request(function(){
        test += 1;
        y++;
        if(y >= whatev.length){
            //stop looping and trigger callback (alert)
            callback();
        }else {
           loop(whatev);
            }
   });

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var test = 0;
    var whatev = [1,2,3,4,5];
    loop(whatev,function(){
       alert(test);
    });
});
```